# Gsub - regex: Replace all commas except ones between quotes or brackets

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to write a regex that identifies all commas, with some exceptions:

- Commas between two "-signs should be ignored
- Commas between brackets [ ] should be ignored

And substitutes them with some special character (for instance `¤`) using `gsub`.

So for this example:

```
something=somethingElse, someThird="this is, a message with a comma!", someFourth=[ this, is, some, list ]
```

I would like the following result:

```
something=somethingElse¤ someThird="this is, a message with a comma!"¤ someFourth=[ this, is, some, list ]
```

I have found a few regexes that identifies these commas (like the in the answer below), but neither seem to work with gsub (they replace too much or nothing at all..)

Comment: Please read the first bullet point [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290740/3764814) (add a language tag).

Comment: Which language/tool are you using?

Comment: It's for use with logstash, I'll have to check..

Comment: Doesn't say, all it says is "These characters form a regex character class and thus you must escape special regex". But does not seem to be perl syntax at least. Lets try with Javascript since I don't know..

Comment: Logstash uses grok and grok uses Oniguruma regex syntax `http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt`   ==> ONIG_SYNTAX_RUBY

Comment: @Andie2302 I'll change my tagging then.

Answer (score 2):

As long as quote and brackets are balanced and there is no escaped instances you can use this regex with lookahead:

```
/,(?=(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)(?![^\[]*\])/g
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wM8uX9/3)

---

**Update:** Here is working ruby code:

```
str = 'something=somethingElse, someThird="this is, a message with a comma!", someFourth=[ this, is, some, list ]';

print str.split(/\s*,(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)(?![^\[]*\])\s*/);
```

**Output:**

`["something=somethingElse", "someThird=\"this is, a message with a comma!\"", "someFourth=[ this, is, some, list ]"]`

[Online Code demo](http://ideone.com/Usg7T0)

Comment: No you don't need `gsub` for this. You will need to use `split` for this. Check my updated answer with `ruby` code and a **code demo link**.